# Connecting to an external server / database using dplyr

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I'm trying to connect to a database that is located in an external server using dplyr's

```
src_postgres(dbname = NULL, host = NULL, port = NULL, user = NULL, 
                 password = NULL, ...)
```

So far so good, I've got all the parameters I need to connect to the database. The problem is that the server where the database is located requires an authentication too (username and password).

I tried creating a connection with `?pipe` but seems like it only works when trying to extract *files* from a remote server.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Good news! I do this all the time and it's not hard :)

## Two steps:

### 1.  Create SSH key and put on remote server

from https://serverfault.com/posts/241593/edit

Generate ssh keys on your local machine:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

And press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for empty passphrase to result in:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

Copy your keys to the target server

```
ssh-copy-id id@server
```

Check that this worked with `ssh 'id@server'`, and check folder `.ssh/authorized_keys` for the ssh keys.

You should know be able to log in with `$ ssh id@server`

### 2. Forward your database port to your local machine

You should know be able to use

```
ssh -fN id@server
```

to initiative an SSH connection and forward ports on to your local host. 
You may need to adjust the `-p` parameter to `ssh` to select the correct port.

Once you can successfully forward the port, you should be able to use `src_postres()` from your *local* machine to access the remote database.

You can also start your R script with

```
system("ssh -fN id@server")
```

or put the command in your `.Rprofile`

#### 3. (optional)

Also, maybe you don't want your `id` and `server` address in your scripts, say, if you were going to give them to a client, or put them on github.

Then, edit or create file (on local machine) `.ssh/config` with the following content:

```
Host my_ssh
User id
Hostname server
```

and then you can just use `ssh -fN my_ssh`

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is by connecting via `DBI` and then using the open connection with `dplyr`.  For example:

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())
db_table <- tbl(con, "my_table")
db_table %>%
  group_by(one_var) %>%
  tally()
```